# An unclear (maybe wrong) proof of a theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis

Look at the following theorem taken from the book "Complex Analysis - E. Freitag, R. Busam", considering that a domain, according the authors, is a path connected open subset of the complex plane:

[image]

Now the implications  $a)\Rightarrow b)$ and $b)\Rightarrow c)$ are clear, but let's examine the following proof of the part  $c)\Rightarrow a)$

[image]

*The unclear passages:*

1. To show that $F$ is differentiable in a generic point $z_0$, it is verified the     equality $F(z)= F(z_0) + f(z_0)(z-z_0)+ r(z)$ **only for $z\in U_\rho(z_0)$**. I think that $z$ should be a generic point of $D$ and not only a point lying in a disk with center $z_0$.
2. Assuming that it is enough to take $z\in U_\rho(z_0)$, the relation $|f(z)-f(z_0)|<\epsilon$ is true only if $|z-z_0|<\delta$. But $\delta<\rho$, so if the segment $\sigma(z_0,z)$ comes out from the disk $U_\delta(z_0)$ we can have that $|f(z)-f(z_0)|\ge\epsilon$.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Differentiability is a local property, so to show that $F$ is differentiable in $z_0$, we need only consider the value of $F$ in a small neighbourhood of $z_0$. And to show that $\dfrac{F(z)-F(z_0)}{z-z_0} \to f(z_0)$, we only need to show that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert r(z)\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon\lvert z-z_0\rvert$ for all $z$ with $\lvert z-z_0\rvert < \delta$. When we choose $\delta < \rho$, the segment between $z_0$ and $z$ stays in $U_\rho(z_0)$.

Comment: The segment $\sigma(z_0,z)$ comes out from $U_\delta(z_0)$, not from $U_\rho(z_0)$.

Comment: No. Whenever $z \in U_\delta(z_0)$, the entire segment $\sigma(z_0,z)$ is contained in $U_\delta(z_0)$. $U_\delta(z_0)$ is a disk, and the segment is part of a radius of that disk.

Comment: I'm not convinced. By definition, a function $F$ is differentiable in $z_0$ iff does exist a linear (in the variable $z-z_0$) function $L$ such that $F(z)=F(z_0)+L(z-z_0)+r(z)$ where $\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{r(z)}{z-z_0}=0$. This for all $z$ in the domain of the function. It is clear that the differential is a local property ecc... but in the definition $z$ is generic.

Comment: For $z$ not in $U_\rho(z_0)$, just define $r(z) = F(z) - F(z_0) - L(z-z_0)$. You can write it as an integral over some path from $z_0$ to $z$, but that doesn't matter. What matters is the limit $z\to z_0$, and for all $z$ sufficiently near, we choose the representation as the integral over the segment between $z_0$ and $z$. That means, for all sufficiently near $z$, we have the estimate.